# Take Smooth Shading into account with Normals Bake

Tags: texture-baking, normals, baking

I am working with a software suite that ignores imported normals and relies entirely on a baked normal map.  This messes up the shading of my model as I cannot use the "Smooth Shading" option to smooth vertex normals.

Is there a way to bake this smooth shading into a normal map?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you "cannot" use smooth shading. That software ignores normals, but it doesn't mean you cannot smooth the mesh for baking normal map in Blender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the *bake selected to active* feature.

1. Duplicate your object.
2. Set one copy to smooth, and the other to sharp.
3. Add a UV map and image to the sharp one.
4. Select the smooth one first, then the sharp one (so the sharp one is active).
5. Enable *Selected to active* in the bake settings.
6. Set *Bake Mode* to *Normals*.
7. Press *Bake*!

You can also use this trick to add bevelled edges for low-poly models. Just add a bevel modifier to the "smooth" object.

[image]

Comment: By the way, that UV mapping shown above may not work well because of the interpolation between faces. You might need to make a UV map that has each face in its own island.